# return a summation of all integers ended with digit '3' from a number of list using recursive function

Tags: python, list, recursion

I am new to python and now I am struggling with recursive function. I can write it in normal function but I can't figure out to write in recursive function.

```
def AddNumWith3(numList):
    sum = 0
    for i in numList:
        if i % 10 == 3:
            sum += i
numList = [1,13,13,3,34,89,90]
print(f'The result is {AddNumWith3(numList)}.')
```

Comment: I'd recommend checking some recursive examples and understanding the logic, then attempting to do it yourself. If we just provide the solution you will not learn anything. Take a look at https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/  and try implementing it yourself. In short, at each call you need to process the first element of the list and call the function recursively passing all elements except the first. Then take a special case when the list has only one element

Comment: it is mandatory to use a recursive function to do this?

Comment: You have a more basic problem: Your function doesn't return `sum`.

Comment: @ helloworld04 few zings: 1- is not a good idea to override ```sum``` 2- the fucntion in your example  is not a recursive function, the answer by islam is recursive because it call it self. 3-  your problem is you forgot to return a value you need to add ```return sum```. 4- if you want you can use list comprehensions ```sum([i for i in numList if i % 10 == 3])```.

Answer (score 2):

```
def AddNumWith3(numList,sum=0):
    if numList:
        i = numList.pop()
        if i % 10 == 3:
             sum += i
        return AddNumWith3(numList,sum=sum)
    else:
        return sum

numList = [1,13,13,3,34,89,90]
print(f'The result is {AddNumWith3(numList)}.')
```

Comment: Nice answer @islam abdelmoumen